# Coding Multiple Leaderboards

Tags: objective-c, ios7, game-center

I am making a game in which the player can achieve a positive high score or a negative low score depending on the choices they make. The high score has been working fine, but I'm having trouble with the low score.

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer{
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    if (viewController != nil) {
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
            _gameCenterEnabled = YES;

            // Get the default leaderboard identifier.
            [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {

                if (error != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
                else{
                    _leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
                }
            }];
        }

        else{
            _gameCenterEnabled = NO;
        }
    }
};
}


-(void)reportScore{

GKScore *highscore = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
highscore.value = HighScoreNumber;

[GKScore reportScores:@[highscore] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];


-(void)showLeaderboardAndAchievements:(BOOL)shouldShowLeaderboard{
GKGameCenterViewController *gcViewController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];

gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self;

if (shouldShowLeaderboard) {
    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = _leaderboardIdentifier;
}
else{
    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
}

[self presentViewController:gcViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

You'll notice leaderboardidentifier, it is useful for reporting scores to the default leaderboard, but when I try to get it to work for two different ones, the code shuts down.

I've tried adding this to "Report Score":

```
GKScore *lowscore = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:_leaderboardIdentifier];
lowscore.value = LowScoreNumber;

[GKScore reportScores:@[lowscore] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

}

Then, I change the leaderboard identifiers to match itunesconnect, but I'm not sure how I need to change authenticateLocalPlayer and shouldShowLeaderboardandAchievements.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with game center. I have two games on the App Store that have multiple leaderboards (Squared!! and Primes!).

Instead of having one method for each leaderboard I made one method for submitting scores. Here is that method:

```
-(void) submitScore:(int64_t)score Leaderboard: (NSString*)leaderboard
{

    //1: Check if Game Center
    //   features are enabled
    if (!_gameCenterFeaturesEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    //2: Create a GKScore object
    GKScore* gkScore =
    [[GKScore alloc]
     initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:leaderboard];

    //3: Set the score value
    gkScore.value = score;

    //4: Send the score to Game Center
    [gkScore reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(NSError* error) {

         [self setLastError:error];

         BOOL success = (error == nil);

         if ([_delegate
              respondsToSelector:
              @selector(onScoresSubmitted:)]) {

             [_delegate onScoresSubmitted:success];
         }
     }];


}
```

When you want to submit your high scores all you have to do is add something like:

```
[[GCHelper sharedGameKitHelper] submitScore:myLowScore Leaderboard:TELS];
[[GCHelper sharedGameKitHelper] submitScore:myHighScore Leaderboard:TEHS];
```

GCHelper is the class that contains my submitScore:Leaderboard: method.

To view your leaderboards or achievements within your app try this:

```
- (void) presentLeaderboards {
    GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController*) gameCenterViewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) presentAchievements {
    GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
```

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Hi, please respond to this answer! I have answered your question!